# Not able to bind a action link to an html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a dynamic link in my javascript file which generates a dynamic link in order for the user to download a file.  I would link to place the link inside of a button in order for the user to press the button instead of the link.  however when I place the link inside of the button it seems like the link is no longer binded to the button.  Not sure what I am doing wrong, I seen examples where they are doing it my way.

**HTML**

```
<button class="k-button" id="ResultButton" style="display: none;"></button>
```

This is where I am creating my button in my "index.cshtml file.

**Javascipt**

```
   var csvData = data.result;
            var buffer = csvData;
            var uri = "data:text/csv;charset=utf8," + encodeURIComponent(buffer);
            var fileName = "resultCSV.csv";

            var link = document.createElement("a");
            if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
                // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
                link.setAttribute("href", uri);
                link.setAttribute("download", fileName);
            }
            else if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
                link.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
                    var blob = new Blob([buffer], {
                        "type": "text/csv;charset=utf-8;"
                    });
                    navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
                }, false);
            }

            link.innerHTML = "Export to CSV";
           // I think I may be doing this incorrect
            document.getElementById("ResultButton") .appendChild(link);
            $("#ResultButton").show();

        } else {
            alert("Your Search Cameback Empty Please Check Your Selections And Retry");
        }
```

I think I may doing this incorrect.  Seems when I am trying to bind this link to my button it overrides the link.  Because when I  `document.body.appendChild(link);`
 it gives me the link properly, but when I bind it to the button it just refreshes the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will make it look like a button.

```
>  var myATag = '<a href="somelink" type="button" class="k-button"
> id="ResultButton"/>';
```

Remove the button code. Create a div and at the end of your function do.

```
 $("#mydiv").html(myATag);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its because you are appending `link` as child of the button, then clicking button wont initiate click of link.So instead of

```
document.getElementById("ResultButton") .appendChild(link);
$("#ResultButton").show();
```

this you sholud give

```
$("#ResultButton").click(function(){
      link.click();
});
```